# Add language (LTR/RTL) mechanism to bundles MVC 4

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

**Background**

- I am building a multilingual system
- I am using MVC 4 bundles feature
- I have different `Javascripts` and `Styles` files for Right-To-Left (RTL) and Left-To-Right (LTR) languages

Currently i handle this scenario as follow:

**BundleConfig File**

```
 //Styles for LTR 
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstarp").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/CustomStyles.css"));

 // Styles for RTL
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapRTL").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap-rtl.css",
            "~/Content/CustomStyles.css"));

 //Scripts for LTR
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/CmsCommon.js"
            ));

 //Scripts for RTL
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/bootstrapRTL").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-rtl.js",
            "~/Scripts/CmsCommon.js"
            ));
```

**Implementation in the views:**

```
@if (this.Culture == "he-IL")
{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapRTL")
}
else
{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
}
```

**The question:**

I was wondering if there is a better way to implement it, i was hoping for:

Handle the logic of detecting which culture and pull the right file in the bundles (Code behind) not in the Views.

So in the views all i will have to do is calling to one file.

If i am leaving the logic in the views its means that i will have to handle it in each view. I want to avoid it.

Comment: btw it' bootstRAP bit bootstARP ;)

Comment: Have you considered an html helper instead?

Comment: You mean using HTML helper to get the name of the file?

Comment: But I want to use bundles feature. And something I need to include buth file LTR and RTL within the bundles deceleration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try custom HTML helper:

```
public static class CultureHelper
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderCulture(this HtmlHelper helper, string culture)
    {
        string path = GetPath(culture);
        return Styles.Render(path);
    }

    private static string GetPath(string culture)
    {
        switch (culture)
        {
            case "he-IL": return "~/Content/bootstarpRTL";
            default: return "~/Content/bootstarp";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @oCcSking: Thanks :) Usually in MyMvcApp\Helpers\CultureHelper.cs

Comment: @abatishchev kindly check my relative question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912475/mvc4-change-web-direction-for-all-pages

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use a switch and magic strings. You can check if a Culture is RTL with this property:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft
```